# Encoding not working when email send by Powershell

Tags: powershell, encoding, utf-8

Im sending a testemail via powershell like

```
$messageParameters = @{
    Subject    = "Email Tool"
    Body       = Get-Content "C:\body.txt" | out-string
    From       = "Info <info@xy.de>"
    To         = "Me <me@xy.de>"
    SmtpServer = "mail.xy.de"
    Encoding   = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding
}

send-mailmessage @messageParameters -BodyAsHtml
```

everything is working find except the encoding.

if i don't use encoding some characters are send as `??`

and if i use it, what i actually want to do, than i get this `Ã„ Ã– Ãœ`

but it should be `ä ö ü` and not this above.

If i don't send the mail as HTML it works.

How can i send the mail with the right encoding AND as html ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the problem is that your text-file is getting jumbled when you are reading it into a variable as non-utf8.

I would try getting the text file as UTF-8 and keeping the Encoding line.

`Body       = Get-Content "C:\body.txt" -Encoding UTF8 | Out-String`

EDIT: Added Out-String per Dwza.

Comment: thank you very much! this was exact what i was looking for :D

Comment: @Dwza, Yea, good catch. I sometimes forget that Powershell usually returns objects. Edited my answer.